# Consistency on container, or item type?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, consistency, sidebar

[image]

I have a question which relates to the attached image. I have a sidebar with a thumbnail image which relates to three types of items - images (mainly) - pdf's and videos.

When someone lands on a PDF, they would hit the "View" icon to open it up in a lightbox, where they can navigate through the various pages.

If an image is available in a higher resolution, then when you hit the "View" icon then you would get a lightbox with a larger image inside.

However, with a video - I put in the viewer in place of the thumbnail, so that the user could play the video straight from the item page - rather than perform the "View" action.

Is this acceptable, or for consistency should there always be a "View" action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main advantage of maintaining consistency here is, reducing different operation modes user needs to be aware of** (launch in place, launch in modal, etc.)

Also, you get much more control on the size of video:

- If the embeded video size is too small, user is most likely going to go in full screen mode. May even be annoying since it screams a necessary additional action on the user's part.
- If you launch the video in a modal, you can give it a quite reasonable screen space and reduce the necessity of going full screen.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that - the fact that you can view the video in a larger space is of course a great factor.